# How do I avoid repeating a SUMIF forumla for multiple worksheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a home budget workbook in Excel where I have my checking, savings, and credit card account transaction histories on separate sheets. I have categorized all expenses (e.g. Rent, groceries, paycheck) and added them by category and month on a separate sheet.

The formula I use to do this looks like this

```
=SUMIFS('CHK'!DepositWithdrawalCol,'CHK'!CategoryCol,"CategoryName",...)
    + SUMIFS('SV'!DepositWithdrawalCol,'SV'!CategoryCol,"CategoryName",...) 
    + SUMIFS('CC'!DepositWithdrawalCol,'CC'!CategoryCol,"CategoryName",...)
```

I have a few other criteria for each `SUMIFS` that group transactions on each sheet by date so I can break down expenses by month.

Is there anyway to turn the bulky equation above into something like this:

```
=SUMIFS('ALL SHEETS'!DepositWithdrawalCol,'ALL SHEETS'!CategoryCol,"CategoryName",...)
```

Comment: It would require using the volatile INDIRECT, so I'd only really recommend it if the number of sheets in question were quite large (or else variable). But three (fixed) sheets only? I'd probably stick with what you've got.

Comment: @XORLX The reason I asked the question is because I am adding two more accounts to the book, and was wondering if I could simplify. `INDIRECT` looks scary so I might keep the horribly long equation

Comment: @XORLX Does a volatile function really matter here? The issue with volatility is performance, correct? If so, will it really inhibit performance for a personal budget tracker?

Comment: @Kyle Good point, though it could also be argued that it is still not a given that a "personal budget tracker" might not - eventually - end up on the large side.

Comment: @XORLX Very true. I guess I am assuming here (I know the risks :)), but if OP has 5 accounts, even if they each had 10,000 transactions (unlikely, very unlikely), I still doubt this is going to make your workbook choppy. I'm not trying to argue or anything as I think both points are valid, I am more bringing this up because it may be the best and easiest solution for the OP and I don't want to steer this to another solution that may not be as good.

Answer (score -1):

Excel 3-D aggregation works for SUM, MIN, MAX, AVERAGE, etc. The list of formulas that support 3-D reference can be found here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6

You cannot use 3D reference in SUMIF and SUMIFS.

Similar question have been answered here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/3-d-sumif-function/73d8eb35-79cd-4ab0-ad7f-93e88e9d138b

*Sadly you are out of luck, so you'll need to consider using VBA*

Comment: This is perfectly achievable using worksheet formulas alone, so I'm not sure how constructive, nor useful, a statement such as "Sadly you are out of luck, so you'll need to consider using VBA" is. What's more, a little more research would have told you what those other "etc." functions which handle 3D referencing are, e.g. :https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-3-D-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6

Comment: @XORLX you are very right! I did insufficient research before I post my answer. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. If it is achievable, can you please post an answer?